# Any option for Angular CLI to also add ngOnDestory to component when run "ng g component"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there a flag for `ng generate` or any configuration to add to `angular.json` so when you run  `ng generate component-name` it'll automatically add `ngOnDestroy` to the component just like it does `ngOnInit` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom schematics using `@angular-devkit/schematics-cli` and the `schematics` command, and you could add `ngOnDestroy` to components if it suits you.

However, it doesn't seem possible out of the box to simply add the `ngOnDestroy`.

Checkout [this medium article](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-custom-angular-schematics-5c50cf90cdb4), that talks about how to use custom schematics.